# How do I perform these common administrator D3 multivalue tasks in jBASE?

Tags: multivalue, pick, multivalue-database, jbase

[jbase](/questions/tagged/jbase)[multivalue-database](/questions/tagged/multivalue-database)[pick](/questions/tagged/pick)[multivalue](/questions/tagged/multivalue)

1. This is how D3 lists the accounts in the system.
   `SORT ONLY MDS WITH A1 = "D]""Q"`
   *Not sure how to do this in jBASE.*
2. This is how D3 lists the users that can log into the system.
   `SORT USERS`
   *Not sure how to do this in jBASE.*
3. This is how D3 shows the current user or a number of users with their port#, user-id, and account-name.
   `WHO`
   `WHO USERID`
   `WHO PORT#`
   `WHO`
   *jBASE does have a "WHO" command, but is there a way to see who the user is as well?*
4. This is how D3 logs off a port.
   `LOGOFF PORT#`
   `RESET-USER PORT#*`
   *jBASE does have a LOGOFF, but not sure how to logoff the correct user/port.*
5. This is how D3 shows the available verbs on the account.
   `LIST-VERBS`
   *Not sure how to do this in jBASE.*
6. When using jBASE `LIST-LOCKS`, jBase returns a PORT/PID.
   *How do I determine the User ID from the PORT/PID information?*

Can you also point me in the direction to find **jBASE documentation** for these questions so I can avoid asking these questions of support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. List accounts in system.
   IMHO - jBase accounts are more system related (windows or unix users) and jBase works around it's current working directory. However, in jBase you have the "SYSTEM" file, that you can list or "CT" (Copy to Terminal).

   CT SYSTEM
2. Here again - all users that can have file system access to a directory with jBASE files can access it.
3. In jBase there is a good command to list all active users or "ports" - WHERE. If you use option "(V" you will also see all details what user is doing. You can also pass user no (port no) to "WHERE (V" command Another useful utility is mw42 - it shows all jBase processes (active users)

   WHERE (V port_no
4. jBase does have LOGOFF command - you pass PORT No as argument. There is also jKill command to kill jbase process

   LOGOFF port_no
5. I think this is what you need - to list Verbs from VOC (or MD):

   LIST VOC WITH F1 EQ "V"
   LIST MD WITH F1 EQ "V"
6. It's better to use SHOW-ITEM-LOCKS, but the user id you will only see from WHERE (V command

Most of the jBase documentation is here: https://docs.jbase.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Accounts in jBASE are different than on D3, in that they were originally associated with a system user and logged into directly, rather than via a LOGTO.

   At a later date, "LOGTO" was implemented, so it is now also possible to create accounts in jBASE just as you might in D3, and entries for these would be found in the designated SYSTEM file.
   There could potentially be more than one of these SYSTEM files, however. In each case, any SYSTEM file being used will be "pointed" to by the JEDFILENAME_SYSTEM environment variable for the "account" into which your are currently logged.
2. In jBASE, users are generally defined for the system rather than for jBASE, i.e. those that are defined as users and can log into the system via Telnet/SSH/Console etc.
3. The jBASE WHO returns both the port number of the logged-on user name.
4. jBASE just uses LOGOFF port#.

   WHERE port# will return the PID associated with that port
5. There is no jBASE equivalent, but you could get a rough idea by running:

   SORT MD WITH *A1 EQ "t"

   this will list keywords/connectives as well.
6. Again, "WHERE port#" should give you the information you need.

   There is also a verbose option, i.e. WHERE port# (V

I should note that these answers related to the Zumasys jBASE version and not the Temenos TAFC version, as there may be some implementation differences.

Mike

Answer (score -1):

5. LIST-VERBS is really just this that shows the executables provided by jBASE:

Windows:   LIST %JBCRELEASEDIR/bin
Linux  :   LIST $JBCRELEASEDIR/bin